# PostgreSQL “Column does not exist” when in DB defined with camelCase

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quoted-identifier

I have interesting situation with Postgres (similar to [PostgreSQL "Column does not exist" but it actually does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41591386/12501050)). I.e. column or table name contains capital letters. In given link above it is about table name.

In my case, in database i have a column "projectId" defined in camelCase (SQL in DB looks like '.. "projectId" integer NOT NULL,..'). In Backend I use Java with Hibernate. When i try to get all entries of the table with named query e.g. "SELECT e FROM ProjectTa e" i get the error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column projectta0_.projectid does not exist
  Hinweis: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "projectta0_.projectId".
  Position: 138
```

SQL log:

```
select projectta0_.id as id1_1_, projectta0_.budget as budget2_1_, projectta0_.completion as completi3_1_, projectta0_.name as name4_1_, projectta0_.projectId as projectI5_1_, p
rojectta0_.status as status6_1_, projectta0_.users as users7_1_ from project_ta projectta0_
```

'FROM "Tablename" ' will solve the problem for table name. How must i adjust my named query if I want just all entries of table. (i do not want to change column name or use name for @Column in my entity)

Comment: The error message suggests that you have a column with a name that looks like the table names and column name combined, all in quotes.

Comment: I have e.g. tablename=project_ta, column=id and column="projectId". I do not think the second column is the combination of tablename and 1st column. If so, what can one do?

Comment: What do you get with `SELECT relname, attname FROM pg_class c INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON c.oid = a.attrelid WHERE c.relname = 'projectta0_';`

Comment: `postgres=# SELECT relname, attname FROM pg_class c INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON c.oid = a.attrelid WHERE c.relname = 'project_ta0_';
 relname | attname
---------+---------
(0 rows)`

Comment: `
  relname   |           attname
------------+------------------------------
 project_ta | ........pg.dropped.5........
 project_ta | ........pg.dropped.6........
 project_ta | budget
 project_ta | cmax
 project_ta | cmin
 project_ta | completion
 project_ta | ctid
 project_ta | id
 project_ta | name
 project_ta | projectId
 project_ta | status
 project_ta | tableoid
 project_ta | users
 project_ta | xmax
 project_ta | xmin
`

Comment: Okay, now try `SELECT relname, attname FROM pg_class c INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON c.oid = a.attrelid WHERE a.attname like '%projectta0_%';`

Comment: `SELECT relname, attname FROM pg_class c INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON c.oid = a.attrelid WHERE a.attname like '%project%';
  relname   |  attname
------------+------------
 project_ta | project_id`

Comment: Another good example why you should avoid quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, helpful link. I have realised that also as stated in description of the question but also interested to adjust my code when i defined a column in db in camelCase.