# postgreSQL error: "constraint does not exist" (but it does exist...)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a database that I'm trying to update, and I can't figure out why I'm getting this weird error about a column not existing. When I access the database using 'heroku pg:psql' I can totally see the column though. I have found a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591386/postgresql-column-does-not-exist-but-it-actually-does) other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200769/postgresql-column-foo-does-not-exist) with similar issues, but haven't been able to resolve it.

Here is my code to execute the INSERT...ON CONFLICT WITH CONSTRAINT...any ideas?

```
const text = 'INSERT INTO "test2" '
+'(route_id, secupdated, retrievedate, traintimeday) '
+'VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4) '
+'ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT traintimeday '
+'DO UPDATE SET (secupdated, secarrival) = (excluded.secupdated, excluded.secarrival) '
+'RETURNING *' ; 
const values = [train_id 
, Math.round(dateNow.getTime()/1000)
, Math.round(dateNow.getDate())
, Math.round(dateNow.getDate()) + stu.stop_id
]; 
pool.query(text, values, (err, res) => {
if (err) {
throw err;
}
console.log('user:', res.rows[0])
})
```

The error message says that 'constraint traintimeday does not exist'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `traintimeday` is not a constraint, instead of:

```
+'ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT traintimeday '
```

use:

```
+'ON CONFLICT (traintimeday) '
```

Comment: Hmm, then I get an error that "there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification"

Comment: @garson I don't know your data model, but assuming `route_id` is the primary key, you probably want to use `ON CONFLICT (route_id)`. This article explains how ON CONFLICT should be used: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/

Comment: that helped - thanks! i needed to define the constraint as a unique identifier.